# Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function! (Trying to add a 'ReactRawTextShadowNode' to a 'LayoutShadow

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

According on [this](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#Drawer) tutorial, this is my component which I use for a **react base** component as a side bar component, and its working very well, but the problem starts when I change list items from `<Text>` to **`<Button>`**

```
    import { Text, Container, Header, Content, List, ListItem, TextBody, Button } from 'native-base';
import { StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

export default class SideBar extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Content style={{ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }}>
                <Container>

                    <Content>
                        <List>
                            <ListItem>
                                <Text>First</Text>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem>
                                <Text>Secount</Text>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem>
                                <Text>Third</Text>
                            </ListItem>
                        </List>
                    </Content>
                </Container>
            </Content>
        );
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> cant add a child that doesn't have a YogaNede to parent without the
>   measure function !(Trying to Add a 'ReactRawTextshadow' to a
>   'LayoutShadowNode' )

cant understand this error at all and didn't saw any thing about it on net!

```
> Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a
> measure function! (Trying to add a 'ReactRawTextShadowNode' to a
> 'LayoutShadowNode') addChildAt
>     ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:199 addChildAt
>     ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:54 setChildren
>     UIImplementation.java:472 setChildren
>     UIManagerModule.java:436 invoke
>     Method.java invoke
>     Method.java:372 invoke
>     JavaMethodWrapper.java:374 invoke
>     JavaModuleWrapper.java:162 run
>     NativeRunnable.java handleCallback
>     Handler.java:739 dispatchMessage
>     Handler.java:95 dispatchMessage
>     MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31 loop
>     Looper.java:135 run
>     MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194 run
>     Thread.java:818
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should Use `<Text>` to display text in `<Button>` like this

```
<ListItem>
    <Button> <Text>First</Text> </Button>
</ListItem>
```

Answer (score 15):

For others landing on this page due to the same error message as the OP,
there are a whole host of issues that can cause same error message.
There is an [GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13243) surrounding this generic error message.

Probably the most common reasons are:

- text to be rendered is not wrapped in **`<Text>`** tags
- **syntax error in JSX** (for example, a `;`, or a malformed tag)
- a space between JSX comments and a JSX tag, if you use Prettier
  (it seems Prettier puts an automatic `;` insertion,
  (solution: move the JSX comment to its own line)
- some value is assumed to be `null`, but it's `undefined`, or an `''`(empty string).
  In the case of an `''`, it would need to be wrapped in `<Text>` (see
  1st item above)
- not wrapping child tags ([ScrollView in particular](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13243#issuecomment-363028001))
- [space between two adjacent tags](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13243#issuecomment-361211438)
- an issue with [CSS](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13243#issuecomment-365675869)

  > If a CSS node has measure defined, the layout algorithm will not visit its children. Even more, it asserts that you don't add children to nodes with measure functions.

I highly recommend taking a gander if you are having trouble finding the source of your error:
**https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13243**

As one person [wrote](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13243#issuecomment-380591803):

> To summarize:
>   This issue is about what React Native perceives to be mal formatted JSX (usually occurring on Android render) and this thread has done a good job documenting the many forms this malformatted JSX can come in.
>
> It Still doesn't solve the need for developers to comb through their code line by line looking for a random semicolons or spaces.
>
> If there is a way to have the stack trace be more specific about the specific offending character or error, that would probably save devs hours of sad debugging..

Answer (score 3):

My error was caused by this code:

```
      {caption && (
        <Text
          style={[styles.tag, { marginBottom: 8 }]}
          numberOfLines={4}
          ellipsizeMode="tail"
        >
          {caption}
        </Text>
      )}
```

For some reason, I need to coerce `caption` from a string to a boolean for it to work on Android. (It worked fine on iOS):

```
     {!!caption && (
        <Text
          style={[styles.tag, { marginBottom: 8 }]}
          numberOfLines={4}
          ellipsizeMode="tail"
        >
          {caption}
        </Text>
      )}
```

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

The error in my case involved `Snackbar` from `react-native-paper`.

**Wrong:**

```
<Snackbar
    visible
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }}
    action={{ label: 'OK', onPress: props.onPress }}
    onDismiss={onDismiss: props.onDismiss}
>
    <View>
        <Text>Some Text</Text>
    </View>
</Snackbar>
```

**Right:**

```
<Snackbar
    visible
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }}
    action={{ label: 'OK', onPress: props.onPress }}
    onDismiss={onDismiss: props.onDismiss}
>
    Some Text
</Snackbar>
```

To my surprise, the solution was the opposite of wrapping into a `<Text>`. Probably a `Snackbar`-specific thing here.